# Using a static NSString in a .h file?

Tags: objective-c, c

I have a configuration `.h` file , which i get access to, from another classes by import it to them .

In that  `.h` class , i have that :

```
static NSString *const charIdList[] =
{

    @"1", @"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"AA",@"BB",@"CC",@"DD",@"EE",@"FF",@"GG",@"HH",@"II",@"J",@"K"
};
```

Which i use in other classes during the program run.
Should i use the static variable here ? or using only a string will be safe ?
What is the scope of the `NSString` in that case-if it will not be `static` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be aware of an effect of defining a `static` variable in a header file: when this happens, each translation unit<sup>1</sup> that includes your header will get its own copy of the `charIdList` array, regardless of whether you use it or not.

A better approach would be establishing this array as a singleton, or if it is truly a constant, defining it as a global, and adding an `extern` for it in the header<sup>2</sup>:

The .h file:

```
extern NSString *const charIdList[];
extern size_t charIdListLength;
```

The .m file:

```
NSString *const charIdList[] = {
    @"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"AA",@"BB",@"CC",@"DD",@"EE",@"FF",@"GG",@"HH",@"II",@"J",@"K"
};
size_t charIdListLength = sizeof(charIdList)/sizeof(charIdList[0]);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> "translation unit" is a fancy name for a `.c` or `.m` file.

<sup>2</sup> Note how the length of the array needs to be defined separately; otherwise, the trick with dividing the `sizeof`s is not going to work.

Comment: Wow great answer thanks a lot , but i dont get why should i set its size? i can check that when ever i need no ?

Comment: btw: every time i import that .h file i create that nsstring, but what is his scope now if he is not a static ?

Comment: @Curnelious No, because the array declared as `exten` isn't going to give you the right size. The `sizeof` operator is evaluated at compile-time, while `extern` references are resolved at link-time, so the division of `sizeof` will come back empty. When you declared `charIdList` `static`, the scope is the translation unit; when you declare it `extern`, it's global.